# What are good offline editors for solidity in windows?

Tags: solidity

I want to use a editor which shows some highlights while writing a solidity code. Please suggest a good editor for writing smart contracts solidity codes for windows. Like gedit for c language.

Answer (score 4):

**1.** With my experience usin solidity, I'll recommend you **[Atom](https://atom.io/)** with 
 its 
 Solidity packages:

- [Linter Solidity](https://atom.io/packages/linter-solidity)
- [Autocomplete Solidity](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-solidity)

The Atom code editor works so well, you can edit documents in remote mode and 
connect with other developers to edit at the same time the same code.
Also it looks fantastic and you can modify all the apperance of the interface 
just by editing it's CSS file.

**2.** Another nice option is use [remix-IDE](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide):

- The ***gh-pages*** branch has always the latest stable build of Remix. It also 
  contains a ZIP file with the entire build. Download it to use offline.
- This is **the only one wich lets you debug transactions** of all of the code editors.

Note: it contains the **latest release of Solidity available at the time** of the packaging. **No other compiler versions are supported.**

**VS Code Solidity package** from [Juan Blanco](https://github.com/juanfranblanco) works fine but is very strict with the line breaks and spaces, if you do not put the ones that the package wants, **it will mark them as errors** and if you're not familiar with that line break syntax, you'll probably get tired of it.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few choices:

- **Visual Studio Code** with its respective [Solidity package](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JuanBlanco.solidity)
- **Sublime text** with its respective [Solidity package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Ethereum)
- **Atom** with its respective [Solidity package](https://atom.io/packages/language-ethereum)
- **Remix IDE**  you can install it in your machine (*advanced*)  [ref](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide#installation).

Note: All packages can be installed from the respective editor, you don't need to download it manually.

Comment: I have installed Sublime text but i don't have any idea about Solidity package as I am new to Solidity. Could you please suggest a reference to install Solidity package with Sublime text editor.

Comment: check here https://medium.com/@abhinavpraksh/ethereum-solidity-language-syntax-in-sublime-1532e6f3646d

Comment: I have gone through it. But i got error on doing this. Below is the thing i got.>>> 
Error validating download (got 6f4c264a24d933ce70df5dedcf1dcaeeebe013ee18cced0ef93d5f746d80ef60 instead of df21e130d211cfc94d9b0905775a7c0f1e3d39e33b79698005270310898eea76), please try manual install

Comment: please try with a google search https://www.google.com/search?q=sublime+install+package+manually&oq=sublime+install+package+&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0l5.12599j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=0